# Ensuring complete udev info on child devices when querying the parent

Tags: shell-script, udev

I am trying to implement a custom function that upon attachment of a USB drive scans all filesystems it contains and then performs operations based on the file system type detected. I went the "recommended" road to write a `udev` rule that triggers an instantiated `systemd` "oneshot" service for the device node, which in turn executes the shell script that "does all the magic (TM)" (for reasons of platform independence, a compiled program was not considered an option here).

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", RUN{program}="/bin/systemctl start usb-drive-manager@$devnode.service"
```

with

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/usb_drive_manager.sh attach %I
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/usb_drive_manager.sh detach %I
```

Inside the shell script, I perform an `ls /sys/.../sdX/sdX*` on the drive's device path to locate any partitions and then query information on these partitions by calling

```
udevadm info /dev/sdXn
```

(where `n` is the partition number) for every processed partition.

**The problem** is now that while this works during "coldplug" tests of the shell script, it does not when the script is triggerd from the `udev` rule because at the time the `udev` event for the *drive* is processed, the information concerning the *partitions* on the drive is not yet gathered by the kernel, i.e. the call to `udevadm info` returns only rudimentary information:

```
P: /devices/.../block/sdb/sdb1
N: sdb1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdb1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/.../block/sdb/sdb1
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=17
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
```

and all relevant information, in particular the `ID_FS_TYPE` and `ID_FS_LABEL` environment variables are (still) missing. Since calling `udevadm settle` while processing `udev` events is a bad idea (and didn't help, either), and even a polling loop with 0.5s sleeps betwenn calls to `udevadm info` didn't work (it took around 1 minute until the information was finally available), I am a bit at a loss here.

Unfortunately, rewriting the `udev` rule so that it applies to *partitions* instead of *drives* is also undesirable since there are cases where people create the file system on the entire USB device instead of creating a single partition that spans the entire device which then contains the file system.

**The question** is now whether

- it is possible to delay processing of a `udev` rule for a given device until all *children* of that device have been processed, or
- there is a system call that I could use inside the shell script that "waits" for all *child* events (if any!) to be finished before going on to query the `udev` data

I reckon that this is quite a long question now; all help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, which pointed me to the use of `blkid` in *udev* rules (see *e.g.* this [ArchLinux-Wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Udev), unfortunately only available in German), I found out that by calling

```
blkid -o udev -p /dev/sdXn
```

instead of

```
udeavdm info /dev/sdXn
```

inside the `systemd`-triggered script it is possible to retrieve complete information about even the child devices of the USB stick whose "add" rule is being processed.

It would seem that the `-p` option here is the key, as it switches to an active probing mode in which the device is actually read out, instead of relying on cached information (cf. e.g. the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/util-linux/blkid.8.en.html) or the [source code](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/blkid.c) of `blkid`).

The `-o udev` option simply serves to format the output in a way similar to the `udevadm` call, although it is not a 100% drop-in replacement as the leading identifier labels of the `udevadm` output (such as `E:`, `P:`, etc.) are missing here.